# JAX-WS - get SOAP headers in web method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

Is there a way to get a list of all SOAP headers in a web method with plain JAX-WS? I know this can be done by using Metro specific classes (`HeaderList hl = messageContext.get(JAXWSProperties.INBOUND_HEADER_LIST_PROPERTY)`). However I'm not sure if I can rely on having that implementation at runtime so I'd like to stick to JAX-WS.

I also know about the `header` attribute of the `@WebParam` annotation. I'd prefer not having to specify the header parameter there. The reason is that my web service has some IDs that are common to all web methods and this would pollute the interface. Also in case another ID comes along or one gets removed again (the spec is not final yet) I'd have to modify every single web method. Also there would be no reason anymore for using a header - it could be a normal method parameter.

The third way I know of is using a handler via `@HandlerChain` but then I have no way of connecting the headers with the executed web method. The IDs I mentioned are important for further processing - they are not just access control that can work independently of the method.

Comment: I don't want to be too pedantic about the _j2ee_ tag but I'm using pure J2SE currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement a request handler, you can store the headers in a thread local, static variable and implement some kind of access mechanism to it for your service method implementation.

Comment: Never thought about ThreadLocal in that context. It's weird to use such low-level concepts when dealing with something high-level like web services but it seems to get the job done.